# Expansion of universe, distance confusion

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, metric-tensor, space-expansion, coordinate-systems

I am having trouble understanding expansion of the universe.
Say my coordinate system uses atomic clock cycles for time and the number of clock cycles for light to bounce back to me for distance.
Say I have an object at the same coordinate in my coordinate system all the time. Is my interpretation that since the universe is expanding it would get a bigger distance with the metric tensor if it was still, so it is in fact moving towards me even though its coordinates are fixed, correct or wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have got confused by a very common misunderstanding of the expanding universe. For a flat universe (the simplest case) the distance between an object at the origin and an object at some position $(x,y,z)$ is given by:

$$ \ell^2 = a^2(t)\left( x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \right) $$

where the function $a(t)$ is called the scale factor. For an expanding universe the scale factor increases with time and this means the distance $\ell$ increases with time even when the position $(x,y,z)$ is constant. It appears that distance to an object increases even though the object isn't moving.

Where the confusion comes in is that the coordinates, $x$, $y$ and $z$, are [comoving coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_and_proper_distances) that are are not simply distances in the usual sense that we measure distances using rulers or whatever measuring device we want. The distance we would measure by stretching a measuring tape out to the object is called the proper distance - the Wikipedia article I linked above explains the difference between proper distance and comoving distance.

If we take your example of a distant object that is stationary relative to you then in your coordinates that object has a constant position and a zero velocity. Alternatively in comoving coordinates the position of the object changes with time and it has a non-zero velocity. As long as you stick to the same coordinate system the behaviour is as you'd expect. The conclusion that distance changes even though the object is stationary arises only when you mix up the two coordinate systems.

Answer (score 0):

How is your coordinate system set up? If your clocks are used to set up a coordinate system where coordinates indicate physical distance, then by construction the clocks aren't moving towards you.

On the other hand, in cosmology, we usually consider a coordinate system where the spatial coordinates do not represent physical distance. Physical distance is measure by the scale factor times the coordinate distance. So if your clocks are at fixed comoving coordinates, then the distance between you and your clocks keeps growing.